# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible/Tried with ID as well as other combinations of CSS selector

Tags: webdriver

boolean display=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#txtkeyword[placeholder='Job title']")).isDisplayed();=false
        boolean select=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#txtkeyword[placeholder='Job title']")).isSelected();=false
        boolean enable=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#txtkeyword[placeholder='Job title']")).isEnabled();=true

Comment: Initially I tried with ID but when I found driver.findElement(By(ID)).size()>1 then I changed it to CSS selector.

Comment: would you please share the HTML code snippet, it would help to identify the issue.

Comment: <input name="body_0$contentcolumn_0$sectionheaderinsert_0$txtkeyword" type="text" id="txtkeyword" class="inFieldLabel form-control keywordHelper showRecentSearches" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Job title" buttonid="body_0_contentcolumn_0_sectionheaderinsert_0_hlksearchJobs">

Comment: My Code:  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#txtkeyword[placeholder='Job title']")).sendKeys("part");

Comment: please update the question as per guideline http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I can't find HTML code option in the page. Already updated all the details. Please tell me your further queries to the question as I am in mid of an issue and it would be great if you can help me in that. THanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for an element to not be visible.  It could be covered by a pop-up, the DOM could still be loading, you may have to scroll it into view.

For the first instance, take a screenshot on failure and see if the element is covered. I use the following for cucumber-jvm. You can google how to do it for whatever framework you are using.

```
@After
public void captureScreenshotOnFailure(Scenario scenario){
    try {
        if (scenario.isFailed() && driver !=null) { 
            System.out.println("***>> Scenario failed: "+scenario.getStatus());
            try {
                driver augemented = new Augmenter().augment(webDriver);
                byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) augemented).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);

                scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    } finally {
        if (driver !=null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

For the DOM not finished loading, wait for it.

```
Wait<driver> wait_element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 80);
WebElement jobTitleElement = wait_element.until(
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(
    "input#txtkeyword[placeholder='Job title']")));
```

If the wait fails then the element just isn't there.

If the wait succeeds then scroll to the element. If the element was a button you could click() it after the moveToElement(). It is not but including the code just to be complete.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(jobTitleElement).click().build().perform();
```